# Is there any possible ways to bypass cloudflare security checks?

Tags: security, server, recaptcha, captcha, cloudflare

We all know, sometimes cloudflare like to check their client visitor to make sure that the visitor isn't a real human. The security check require us to pass Google Recaptcha. What i want to ask is it possible to pass that in using our own server (Even with remote server and answer the captcha by ourself etc) and how?

Comment: if the security check was easy to bypass programmatically, doesn't it seem likely that criminals etc might choose to use the same technique?

Comment: Not only by programmatically way, but also with the real human controlling the server.

Answer (score 14):

When you visit a site which is protected by cloudflare, it would contain a security check which you cannot bypass and on failing eventually your *access* is denied and you are redirected to the [captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835) challenge page due to the requests from low reputation IP addresses.

> IP Reputation is calculated based on [Project Honeypot](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/), external public IP information, as well as internal threat intelligence from the [Web Application Firewall](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172016) and [DDoS](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172676).

---

### Solution

In these cases the a potential solution would be to use the [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) to initialize the *Chrome Browsing Context*.

[undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) is an optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io. It automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

- Python Sample Code:

  ```
  import undetected_chromedriver as uc
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get('https://bet365.com')
  ```

---

### Alternative

An alternate solution would be to whitelist your IP address through the [Project Honey Pot](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/search_ip.php) website using the following steps:

- You have to edit the [Page Rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-PageRules-) which trigger certain actions whenever a request matches one of the URL patterns you define following two basic principals:

  - Only the highest priority matching page rule takes effect on a request.
  - Page rules are prioritized in descending order in the Cloudflare dashboard, with the highest priority rule at the top.
- Disabling the [Under Attack mode(advanced DDOS protection)](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170076) in the Settings tab of the Firewall app or via a [Page Rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172336-How-do-I-create-a-PageRule-), Security Level presents a JS challenge page.

---

### tl; dr

You can find the detailed end-to-end process in the video tittled [Attention Required one more step captcha CloudFlare Error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGFKTkqEsu8).

Answer (score 5):

Of course it's possible in several ways. One of that would be using a "real simulated browser" which parses the javascript.

Another way is - if you run it on a headless server - to use a headless browser which does that for you. After the first request you can store the cookies and reuse it in a basic http client like jsoup (java).

Example using JBrowserDriver (headless) and java:

```
JBrowserDriver jBrowserDriver = null;

public JBrowserDriver getDriver(Boolean headless) {
        if (jBrowserDriver == null) {

            log.info("JBrowser was null, initalizing");

            jBrowserDriver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder()
                    .timezone(Timezone.EUROPE_BERLIN)
                    .ssl("compatible")
                    .cache(true)
                    .javascript(true)
                    .headless(headless)
                    .userAgent(UserAgent.CHROME)
                    .logTrace(true)
                    .loggerLevel(Level.ALL)
                    .build());

        }
        return jBrowserDriver;
}


private void testFunction() {
 // .. 
    jDriver.get("https://cloudflare.site");
    driverCookies = jDriver.manage().getCookies();
    
    HashMap<String, String> cookieMap = new HashMap<>();

    driverCookies.forEach(cookie -> cookieMap.put(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue()));

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(requestPage).cookies(cookieMap).get();

}
```

I am not responsible for any damage done by bypassing cloud flare, but aslong as human can bypass it, it will always be possible to do that with simulated clients.

Edit: If there is also a recaptcha behind, it might be hard to bypass that. But usually this happen if you are not logged in to a google account, or the server believe that you are a bot. Just reuse the cookies generated by a google auth and make sure that you always reuse and send the same cookies.

Cloudflare also checks -not sure about that- if your client is requesting the assets like css and javascripts.

You might need to request them aswell with a fake-client.

Answer (score 1):

For yourself, yes you can.

You can create a [custom rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-PageRules-) for your IP addresses and set the *Security Level* to *Essentially Off*.

The [`Security Level`](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170056-What-does-Cloudflare-s-Security-Level-mean-) is what controls whether or not to present the challenge to a particular visitor.

By disabling the security level for your IP addresses you can effectively bypass this protection for yourself on your own site.

Comment: That won’t help on others’ sites…

Comment: The question specifically asks how to bypass it for their own server.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question does not suggest the language in which the user wants to bypass cloudflare protection, I will provide the code for node.js:

Libs:

```
npm i puppeteer-extra puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth puppeteer
```

nodejs:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const { executablePath } = require('puppeteer')

const link = 'https://www.g2.com/'

const getHtmlThoughCloudflare = async (url) => {
  puppeteer.use(pluginStealth())
  const result = await puppeteer
    .launch({ headless: true })
    .then(async (browser) => {
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.goto(url)
      const html = await page.content()
      await browser.close()
      return html
    })

  console.log(` HTML: ${result}`)
  return result // html
}

getHtmlThoughCloudflare(link)
```