# How to extract the temporary email address from https://temp-mail.org using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, clipboard, webdriverwait

I'm trying to access : temp-mail.org they remove to possibility of extracting the email using an API, so i was trying to extract it using python (selenium)

I'm using the following code to **avoid detection** by **cloudflare**, but still, sometimes I got caught.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from streamlit import caching
from selenium import webdriver
 
 
 
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd()+"chromedriver.exe")



PROXY =[
{"host": "104.248.123.76", "port":18080},
{"host": "136.144.54.195", "port":80}
]
 
index = int(uniform(0, len(PROXY)))
PROXY = PROXY[index]["host"]+":"+str(PROXY[index]["port"])
 
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy']={
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
 
}

caching.clear_cache()
driver.delete_all_cookies()

driver.get('website')
```

Should I need to change the website from which I'm **grabbing the proxies** or is there any other solutions!!

Comment: Which website are you trying to get through?

Comment: I'm trying to access : https://temp-mail.org/ 
they remove to possibility of extracting the email using an API, so i was trying to extract it using python (selenium)

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear why you felt [*Cloudflare*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328849/is-there-any-possible-ways-to-bypass-cloudflare-security-checks/64960388#64960388) detects your program as a bot.

To extract the *Temporary Email Address* from https://temp-mail.org/ you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) based solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  import win32clipboard

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn-rds icon-btn bg-theme click-to-copy copyIconGreenBtn']"))).click()
  # get clipboard data
  win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
  data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
  win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
  print(data)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  soton18826@girtipo.com
  ```
- Browser and Console snapshot:
  [image: tempmail]

Comment: I already grabbed the email without using a proxy(the way that you did use),
but in my case i am trying to grab it using a proxy but i get caught by CloudFlare.

Comment: @Onavty _...using the following code to avoid detection by cloudflare..._ you don't really need proxy in this usecase. Now why your proxy is getting detected is altogether  a different issue and can happen for even while accessing https://www.google.com/