# How to automate login to a site which is detecting my attempts to login using selenium-stealth

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, botdetect, selenium-stealth

So, I'm trying to write a script to login on https://us.etrade.com/e/t/user/login

I am using Selenium for this but it somehow detects selenium when it starts and results in a message that says that the servers are crowded and when it happens, I can't log in. I've also tried using undetected-selenium as well as selenium-stealth but both got detected as well. I really need to automate this log in process. I've tried using python requests but that doesn't work. I'm open to any other technology or method that allows me to do this automation. Please help.

Here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--browser')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

stealth(wd,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )

wd.get("https://us.etrade.com/e/t/user/login")
```

Comment: You should use their API!

Comment: Sorry, I know how to use an API but I need to login this way unfortunately.

Comment: Demo creds for login?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide those.

Comment: @Newprogrammer How do you want us to test our solutions?

Answer (score 8):

Demo creds would have helped us to dig deeper into your specific usecase.

However using [*selenium-stealth*](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth) I was able to bypass the detection of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* pretty easily.

> [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) compatible code

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium_stealth import stealth


  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")

  # Chrome is controlled by automated test software
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

  # Selenium Stealth settings
  stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
    )

  driver.get("https://bot.sannysoft.com/")
  driver.save_screenshot('bot_sannysoft.png')
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: bot_sannysoft]

---

With [ETRADE Login page](https://us.etrade.com/e/t/user/login)

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium_stealth import stealth
  import time
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")

  # Chrome is controlled by automated test software
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

  # Selenium Stealth settings
  stealth(driver,
          languages=["en-US", "en"],
          vendor="Google Inc.",
          platform="Win32",
          webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
          renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
          fix_hairline=True,
          )

  driver.get("https://us.etrade.com/e/t/user/login")
  driver.save_screenshot('etrade_com_login.png')
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: etrade_com_login]