# selenium and chromium fingerprint problem?

Tags: selenium, browser, chromium, fingerprint

I want to write a class or function that can change some features of the browser using c# selenium or chromium, but I did not know where to start, can you share if you have a class or function written to change the following features. Can you guide me on how to do it?

Features we want to change:
Canvas fingerprint. , Webgl fingerprint. , Video card specs. , Audio fingerprint. , Audio card specs. , Font list. , Header order, Display specs – resolution , color depth, etc. , userAgent , oscpu , vendor , vendorSub , productSub , buildID , hardwareConcurrency , deviceMemory , and like: getGamepads and getVRDisplays. , Intelligent change of browser language – language format , Geolocation.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/70133896#70133896) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70132565/how-to-automate-login-to-a-site-which-is-detecting-my-attempts-to-login-using-se/70134837#70134837) discussion helps you?