# How to make python selenium less detectable?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

Okay, so I am making a bot for this website to automate account creation. I am using rotating ipv4 proxies and some other anti detection stuff but still being detected every time. Any ideas?

Here's how I'm initializing the driver and what options im using.

```
proxy = random.choice(proxys)
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random

def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=my chrome user data directory here')
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
    driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(cache_valid_range=30).install()),options=options)
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
    print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
    sleep(1)
    while True:
        create_account(driver, catchall)
```

I also have tried chrome profiles, but I cannot make enough of those, and was wondering how I could implement those somehow. Because it seems after the website detects I am a bot, the chrome profile I was using no longer works.

I am being blocked out every time by the website, almost no matter what. Although sometimes it does happen to go through after I make some random changes. But I was expecting everything to be working now as almost everything that they can detect is being changed.

Comment: You can try using Selenium-Profiles or undetected-chromedriver

Comment: If they don't want bots crawling them, why do you think it's OK for you to try to get around it?

Comment: @Barmar the real question is if its possible to bypass, why should it matter?

Answer (score 1):

### [**selenium-stealth**](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/)

To make *Python-Selenium* almost undetectable your best bet would be to use [selenium-stealth](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth#selenium-stealth-) which:

- Passes all public bot tests.
- [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) can do google account login.
- Maintain a normal reCAPTCHA v3 score

---

### A demonstration

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium_stealth import stealth
  import time
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

  # Selenium Stealth settings
  stealth(driver,
          languages=["en-US", "en"],
          vendor="Google Inc.",
          platform="Win32",
          webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
          renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
          fix_hairline=True,
          )
  driver.get("https://bot.sannysoft.com")
  time.sleep(5)
  driver.save_screenshot("sannysoft.png")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: sannysoft.png]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to automate login to a site which is detecting my attempts to login using selenium-stealth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134837/7429447)
- [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70133896/7429447)