# Undetected Chromedriver Alternative

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am unable to run Undetected Chromedriver on Linux (Windows works fine). I am getting a timeout from renderer error and despite catching this error, UC hangs and the browser becomes unresponsive. Since I am unable to debug this, I want an alternative.

How can I replicate some of the functionality of Undetected Chromedriver, either through an alternative Python package or through code?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70133896/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134837/7429447) answer helps you?

Comment: Not really, looking for explanation of what UC does and how I can replicate it through an alternative.

Comment: Also, I am using selenium-stealth already. Any feedback and help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) would be an alternative, but currently has some issues with detection on Chrome v110 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s UC Mode as an alternative.

First `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

try using webdriver with stealth example

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) if ARGS.no_webdriver_manager else webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    stealth(browser,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: thanks, but using that already.