# How to bypass captcha slider in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, captcha

I am working with Python Selenium and the website detects that I am using a robot, I am finding this slider captcha, would you know how to bypass it?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76650586/7058266 may help you with bypassing CAPTCHAs.

Answer (score 0):

### Description:

If you are using chrome you can simply download `undetected-chromedriver` package as well as requests and run the chrome-driver in headless mode.

### Steps:

Install requests and undetected-chromedriver using:

```
pip install requests undetected-chromedriver
```

then use the following in your code:

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--use_subprocess")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://example.com")
```

Try this and you should be good to go.

Comment: this worked !

from seleniumbase import Driver; 

import time;

driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True); 
driver.get(url)

Answer (score 0):

this worked !

```
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time
driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True) 
driver.get(url)
```