# Handle Alert with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

I'm trying to write Login credentials using `send_keys` element method with Selenium on this alert:
[Login Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbnK3.jpg)

I get this alert after clicking on a button in a new window but I can't inspect the elements on this window.

here is my code

```
import time
import pynput
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/dhias/OneDrive/Bureau/stgg/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://10.15.44.177/control/userimage.html")
time.sleep(3)
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.maximize_window()
btn=driver.find_element_by_name("TheFormButton3")
btn.click()
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
obj = driver.switch_to.alert
time.sleep(2)
obj.send_keys('Admin')
time.sleep(2)
```

I get this error that tells me that there is no alert

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I've found a solution..I used the approach where you have to send username and password in URL Request and it worked:

```
http://username:password@the-site.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't acess to the page so I can't try my code but, first I optimized It by adding `WebdriverWait` and the new `By.` function:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = wd.Chrome("C:/Users/dhias/OneDrive/Bureau/stgg/chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

driver.get("http://10.15.44.177/control/userimage.html")
driver.maximize_window()
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "TheFormButton3"))).click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.send_keys('Admin\npassword\n') # \n works as an ENTER key
```

You can try this code to see if the alert really exists or is an element of the webpage:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def is_alert_present(self):
    try:
        self.driver.switch_to_alert().send_keys('Admin\npassword\n') # \n works as an ENTER key
        print('Sucess')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('No Alert Present')
```

Also see [Alerts](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=switch#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert) in the [Selenium Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=switch#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert)

### Also Try:

```
parent_h = browser.current_window_handle
# click on the link that opens a new window
handles = browser.window_handles # before the pop-up window closes
handles.remove(parent_h)
browser.switch_to_window(handles.pop())
# do stuff in the popup
# popup window closes
browser.switch_to_window(parent_h)
# and you're back
```

Comment: After trying your code ,I have found out that there is no alert in the new window because I get a "NoAlertPresentException" and maybe it's an element of the webpage.

Comment: Yes, try the select tool of inspector, the mouse in a box at the top left of editor window, just click on the pop up and the tool will indicate you the right line in the html, feel free to accept the answer if you found it helpful