# Alert popup login and download file using python without using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am trying to download file from a website which prompts for alert login popup for entering username and password,once login file will get downloaded automatically. I want to automate this process. But the examples i am getting using Selenium examples only. I want to do this without selenium.

[image]

Comment: Are you only downloading one file or multiple files?

Comment: It is only one file

Comment: Can you try the solution mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537664/handle-alert-with-python-and-selenium).

Comment: I added an update on how to pass headers data with the post request.  I cannot tell you what these headers are, because I don't have access to the URL that you are trying to connect with.  As I mentioned in our extend chat,  you can get these headers by using the Development tools in Chrome.

Comment: Any updates based on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try using requests in Python [Install](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/)

```
import requests

# set up the authentication credentials
username = "user"
password = "pass"
auth = (username, password)
url = "https://samp.com"
# send an HTTP GET request with the authentication credentials
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
with open("file_to_save.pdf", "wb") as f:
f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Already tried this code, but this doesn't work. this gives the issue Access Denied

Comment: do you know how to use specific web browser in here?

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATED 05.11.2023 at 2:50PM GMT

It might be possible to use `requests.Session` to pass your authentication credentials and then request the file.

You will likely need to pass in the headers with `requests.Session.post`.

This question is difficult to troubleshoot without the URL and the credentials, so I can only provide you guidance on how I would tackle this use case.

```
from requests import Session

# you need to look for these in your browser at I mentioned in the 
# our chat session. You likely need to pass these in with your post request
# passing these might prevent the 403 errors.

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}


with Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    session.auth = ("username", "password")
    auth_connection = session.post('https://somewebsite.com')
    print(auth_connection.status_code)
    if auth_connection.status_code == 200:
        response = session.get('https://somewebsite.com/datafile.csv')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            with open('/path_to_directory_you_want_to_save/file_name.text', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Response status code 403

Comment: I added some additional code to determine the status of the `session.post.` What status code are you getting here?

Comment: Same status code 403

Comment: This line `print(auth_connection.status_code)` gives you a `403`?  If this is the case then your credentials aren't being accepted.  Can you provide the URL for the main page?

Comment: If you cannot share the URL then I need to see the headers for this `auth_connection.headers`

Comment: {'Server': 'AkamaiGHost', 'Mime-Version': '1.0', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': '260', 'Expires': 'Thu, 11 May 2023 03:00:28 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Thu, 11 May 2023 03:00:28 GMT', 'Xonnection': 'close', 'Server-Timing': 'cdn-cache; desc=HIT, edge; dur=1, ak_p; desc="467715_1750514755_24981958_42_44740_0_-";dur=1', 'Akamai-X-True-TTL': '-1', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'}

Comment: Thanks.  So are you getting a 403 on this line print(auth_connection.status_code)?

Comment: yes, getting a 403 on this line print(auth_connection.status_code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253596/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-ramineni-ravi-teja).