# Python bypass Cloudflare using headless selenium while opening the new tab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cloudflare, undetected-chromedriver

I have a website to be scraped, daily around 10k-20k visits to the page. I did it for more than 1 month, and everything is fine.

1. I can access it using the non-selenium browser.
2. For now, using the Selenium browser, there is Cloudflare which blocks me from visiting. After 3 to 5 click on Cloudflare block, it still distinguishes me as a bot.
3. However, under the same Selenium browser, I open this website using a new tab, and it works. However, I still need to click on Cloudflare once to visit the website.

Tried:

1. Pass in user agent
2. `options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)`
3. `options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')`
4. [Selenium headless: How to bypass Cloudflare detection using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289474/selenium-headless-how-to-bypass-cloudflare-detection-using-selenium)
5. selenium_stealth (don't know whether in a correct way)

```
def getDriver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    broswer = uc.Chrome(options=options, version_main=113)

    return broswer
```

How can I modify it to make it work using headless mode?

Current setting: undetected chrome, version = 113

Answer (score 0):

Use [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) instead . It is a Python library designed to enable the use of Chrome WebDriver in a stealthier way, particularly for web scraping and automation tasks. It serves as a patch for Chromedriver, ensuring that it does not trigger anti-bot services such as Distill Network, Imperva, DataDome, or Botprotect.io. The library takes care of automatically downloading the driver binary and applying the necessary patches for improved undetectability.

Installation

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

Usage

```
import undetected_chromedriver
driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: thanks mate for suggestion, but I already implemented undetected chrome and it doesn't work.