# skip cloudflare view source page php

Tags: php

I have this code to fetch the source code of the sites, but there are some sites that use Cloudflare.. and it is not possible to fetch the source code

Is there a way to bypass Cloudflare?

```
// get url of redirect from source url & get url view source
$url = '/';
function get_remote_data($url, $post_paramtrs=false,  $curl_opts=[]){ 
    $c = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //if parameters were passed to this function, then transform into POST method.. (if you need GET request, then simply change the passed URL)
    if($post_paramtrs){ curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (is_array($post_paramtrs)? http_build_query($post_paramtrs) : $post_paramtrs) ); }
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'CookieName1=Value;'); 
        $headers[]= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0";     $headers[]= "Pragma: ";  $headers[]= "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        if (!empty($post_paramtrs) && !is_array($post_paramtrs) && is_object(json_decode($post_paramtrs))){ $headers[]= 'Content-Type: application/json'; $headers[]= 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_paramtrs); }
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); 
    //if SAFE_MODE or OPEN_BASEDIR is set,then FollowLocation cant be used.. so...
    $follow_allowed= ( ini_get('open_basedir') || ini_get('safe_mode')) ? false:true;  if ($follow_allowed){curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);}
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 9);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);    
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, !empty($extra['return_array']));
    //set extra options if passed
    if(!empty($curl_opts)) foreach($curl_opts as $key=>$value) curl_setopt($c, constant($key), $value);
    $data = curl_exec($c);
    if(!empty($extra['return_array'])) { 
         preg_match("/(.*?)\r\n\r\n((?!HTTP\/\d\.\d).*)/si",$data, $x); preg_match_all('/(.*?): (.*?)\r\n/i', trim('head_line: '.$x[1]), $headers_, PREG_SET_ORDER); foreach($headers_ as $each){ $header[$each[1]] = $each[2]; }   $data=trim($x[2]); 
    }
    $status=curl_getinfo($c); curl_close($c);
    // if redirected, then get that redirected page
    if($status['http_code']==301 || $status['http_code']==302) { 
        //if we FOLLOWLOCATION was not allowed, then re-get REDIRECTED URL
        //p.s. WE dont need "else", because if FOLLOWLOCATION was allowed, then we wouldnt have come to this place, because 301 could already auto-followed by curl  :)
        if (!$follow_allowed){
            //if REDIRECT URL is found in HEADER
            if(empty($redirURL)){if(!empty($status['redirect_url'])){$redirURL=$status['redirect_url'];}}
            //if REDIRECT URL is found in RESPONSE
            if(empty($redirURL)){preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)(\r|\n)/si', $data, $m);                 if (!empty($m[2])){ $redirURL=$m[2]; } }
            //if REDIRECT URL is found in OUTPUT
            if(empty($redirURL)){preg_match('/moved\s\<a(.*?)href\=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)here\<\/a\>/si',$data,$m); if (!empty($m[1])){ $redirURL=$m[1]; } }
            //if URL found, then re-use this function again, for the found url
            if(!empty($redirURL)){$t=debug_backtrace(); return call_user_func( $t[0]["function"], trim($redirURL), $post_paramtrs);}
        }
    }
    // if not redirected,and nor "status 200" page, then error..
    elseif ( $status['http_code'] != 200 ) { $data =  "ERRORCODE22 with $url<br/><br/>Last status codes:".json_encode($status)."<br/><br/>Last data got:$data";}
    //URLS correction
    $answer = ( !empty($extra['return_array']) ? array('data'=>$data, 'header'=>$header, 'info'=>$status) : $data);
    return $answer;      
}  
$view_source = get_remote_data($url, $post_paramtrs=false,  $curl_opts=[]);
```

page appears >>> Please Wait... | Cloudflare

Comment: No, that's kind of the point of using Cloudflare...

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: @ramyromeo CloudFlare provides multiple features that protect the Intellectual Property of their customers. One of which [prevents content scraping and other bot-like behaviors](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/bot-management/) like your script performs. One of the methods is to display a CAPTCHA before permitting the request to display the specified webpage, which would require client-side interaction to proceed.

Comment: A related question that covers several methods has already been asked that can be found at [Is there any possible ways to bypass cloudflare security checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50328849/1144627)

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare is a middleware. Your request goes through cloudflare and then to your server. You do not access to your site directly. If site disables cloudflare then you can access the site directly.