# Web scraping with request/selenium/cloudscraper return empty values

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to collect information from a cloudflare-protected website I believe. I've tried three alternatives and they all return empty values. So, I don't know if the site has any blockages or if I'm doing something wrong.

**--Update**

The solution proposed by F.Hoque works, however, when I try to use it in Colab, I only get an empty value.

**Using request**

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

```
url = 'https://www.portaldoholanda.com.br/assaltante-surra/com-pedacos-de-madeira-populares-dao-surra-em-homem-assalt'
```

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
```

```
soup.find('h1',class_="noticia titulo").text # I tried with select too (soup.select('[class="noticia titulo"]'))
```

**Using cloudscraper**

```
import cloudscraper
```

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(scraper.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
```

```
soup.find('h1',class_="noticia titulo").text
```

**Using selenium**

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSessionIdException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

```
river = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
print("Current session is {}".format(driver.session_id))
```

```
driver.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
innerContent = html.find('h1',class_="noticia titulo").text
```

Comment: [cloudflare-protected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960388/7429447) website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,the website is using cloudflare protection.

```
https://www.portaldoholanda.com.br/assaltante-surra/com-pedacos-de-madeira-populares-dao-surra-em-homem-assalt is using Cloudflare CDN/Proxy!

  

https://www.portaldoholanda.com.br/assaltante-surra/com-pedacos-de-madeira-populares-dao-surra-em-homem-assalt is using Cloudflare SSL!
```

Here is the working solution using `cloudScraper` instead of `requests`.

**Script:**

```
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
url = "https://www.portaldoholanda.com.br/assaltante-surra/com-pedacos-de-madeira-populares-dao-surra-em-homem-assalt"
req= scraper.get(url)
#print(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
txt=soup.find('h1',class_="noticia titulo").text
print(txt)
```

**Output:**

```
Com pedaços de madeira, populares dão surra em homem em Manaus; veja vídeo
```

Comment: Hello. For some reason this code in Colab has the following message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @PSCM, You  also can try  another environment to test it. Thanks

Comment: Yes. It works on my local machine. Any idea why it doesn't work in Colab? My project depends on this environment. Thank you!