# I am working with selenium but when i use driver.get i am catching error 1020 access denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, access-denied, pyvirtualdisplay

I created a bot in Python using Selenium, uploaded Ununtu to a remote server, and when I go to the driver.get('correct_url') => site, an access denied error occurs. On windows everything works fine (code is working).

```
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-experimental-cookie-features')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(browser_driver_path), chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(website_link)
```

Already tried: to use undetected_chromedriver. I also performed basic actions from the Internet, turned on cookies, cleared the cache, etc.

Libraries:

- selenium
- pyvirtualdisplay
- webdriver Options

Comment: Error 1020 Access Denied is caused when a firewall rule has been violated on a site. if you can access it normally, then i think the site is just bot protected

Comment: @Akzy
Is there any way I can bypass this protection?

Comment: You can check this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960388/11863448] will help you,